# Can an OpenVPN server track the client os type?

Tags: vpn, openvpn

I was wondering when I connect to an OpenVPN server what kind of information can the server extract from my client?

Obviously the server can detect my user-id, pwd, but can it detect:

- My vpn-client-software (say would it know that I'm connecting using tunnelblick)?
- My O/S (osx, linux, windows, etc)
- My IP (I think the answer to this one is YES)
- My mac-address (aa:bb:cc:...)

---

Not sure how the question @Ohnana has linked answer my question?

I'm not talking about a vpn server tracking my traffic, I'm asking if they can extract information about my machine and my client?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can OpenVPN monitor my passwords in my browser?](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/93392/can-openvpn-monitor-my-passwords-in-my-browser)

Comment: @Ohnana I don't know enough about vpn to see a relation between what they're asking and what I'm asking...

Comment: The second bullet point of the answer stood out as the answer to your question: "If someone runs the OpenVPN server for you then it is a matter of trust..." Since they own the server, they can install extra utilities to fingerprint your machine, capture software banners, and log your IP address.

Comment: True. The server indeed can fingerprint and intercept a lot in theory like Ohnana said. However, using an operating system like e.g Tails solves a lot of these fingerprint issues (https://tails.boum.org/contribute/design/) you can configure any (UNIX/*nix) system to avoid fingerprinting. Yet using Tails is safer against human errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agree with @Ohnana and I have some to add: it is possible via source tailoring to make an OpenVPN client "faceless", without any os/version/libs fingerprint. But if this openvpn is not used as a tunnel for another OpenVPN - first web browser HTTP plain session will tell everything about you